# pydantic values not present

Tags: python, pydantic

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str

    @validator('a')
    def a_valid(cls, v, values):
        print(values)
        return v

Foo(a='a', b='b')
# prints '{}'
```

When I try to access other values in the model, Im getting an empty dictionary.
I'm expecting `a dict containing the name-to-value mapping of any previously-validated fields`

Perhaps Im miss understanding what `previously-validated fields` means

Answer (score 2):

Fields are processed in the order in which they are defined in youyr model. When `a` is being validated, `b` hasn't been set yet. If you need to have access to other fields, you probably want a [`root_validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str

    @root_validator
    def a_valid(cls, values):
        print(values)
        return values


Foo(a="a", b="b")
# prints '{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}'
```

Alternatively, you can change the order of the fields in your mode:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    b: str
    a: str

    @validator("a")
    def a_valid(cls, v, values):
        print(values)
        return values


Foo(a="a", b="b")
# prints '{'b': 'b'}'
```